# Use ::selection selector to change selection color of all children

Tags: html, css

I have two `div` elements with any type of children in it (like `input` and `span`) and I want to change the selection color of all child elements in my first div to `red` and in the second `div` to yellow.

The following does **not** work:

```
#my-div-1::selection
{
  background-color: red;
}

#my-div-2::selection
{
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

I can **not** use the selector like this:

```
::selection
{
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

because this would overwrite the color of the second div and apply to the whole document.

Answer (score 0):

You need to **select all children elements** where the selector should apply to. You can instead write the following:

```
#my-div-1 *::selection
{
  background-color: red;
}

#my-div-2 *::selection
{
  background-color: yellow;
}
```